# How can I extract the value of latitude from table body?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I can't seem to figure out how to return on integer from a table body. The terminal is returning a 'none' type and if I get rid of get.attribute("value") on line 10 nothing prints to the terminal.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Safari()
url = driver.get('http://wsn.spaceflight.esa.int/iss/index_portal.php')

#able to get element from web but returning 'none' value in terminal
latitude = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div')

print(latitude.get_attribute("value"))#something I tried, not working
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the value of *Latitude* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.isst_cd#isst_lat"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Latitude']//following::div[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From inspecting the webpage; you may need to try:

```
latitude = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]')
```

Or this; since it has an ID:

```
latitude = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="isst_lat"]')
```

And to get the content:

```
latitude.text
```

It is a `string`.

Comment: The second part outputs a selenium object. Like so, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="F8359605-C89B-4FB2-9D55-6DFBED3DE520", element="node-88EEB2BB-6CA0-47E4-B5A6-FC0F500DABA7")>, which I've gotten before but now how do I get that object to display an integer?

Comment: I have updated the comment. Call the `.text` and you will get the co-ordinate. It is a string and not an integer.

Comment: @NidhinBoseJ. You can parse the String to Integer

Comment: But I would not know its significance since the output is co-ordinates and hence its unit is not exactly expressed with a float.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the long and lat with below lines.

```
longitude = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='isst_lon']").text
latitude = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='isst_lat']").text
```

If you want to use the css then you can do it with

```
longitude = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#isst_lon').text
latitude = driver.find_element_by_xpath('div#isst_lat').text
```

Comment: I have used this method before and it doesn't output anything to the terminal. Do you think its being stored? Or is it just not return anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use locator by `id` to get `latitude` and `longitude`, like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
url = 'http://wsn.spaceflight.esa.int/iss/index_portal.php'
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'isst_lat')))

latitude = driver.find_element_by_id('isst_lat')
longitude = driver.find_element_by_id('isst_lon')

print(latitude.text)
print(longitude.text)
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

The above code I add `WebDriverWait` until visibility of element located.